# Angular2 cli (2.1.0) how to declare 3rd party library using @types

Tags: angular

I've installed a `@types` module called `x2js` so I can convert my JSON string to XML and I added these in my typings.d.ts then imported it in my component. But it's giving me an error of `X2JS not defined`, I'm using it like this `private J2XML = new X2JS();` I'm following the test.d.ts on their git repo 
[X2JS repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/x2js/xml2json-tests.ts%20how%20to%20use%20it.)

I also tried adding but the result is still the same its the same error `X2JS is not defined`

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/x2js/index.d.ts" />
```

`declare module 'IX2JS';
declare const IX2JS:any;`

Component

`import * as x2js from 'IX2JS';`

How can I declare/import `@types` module in Angular 2 (2.1.0)-cli?

Comment: try import * as x2js from "X2JS";